# Rotate, scale and pan element in UWP

Tags: uwp, gestures

My goals are quite simple. I want to be able to do multiple transformation of an image in my UWP application using primarily touch screen gestures. More precise I want to handle each manipulations like

> Pan (Translate) - One finger gesture to pan image around the canvas.
>
> Scale - pinch to zoom, use center of gestures as zoom center.
>
> Rotate - Standard two finger gesture, use center of gesture as rotation center.

I have created a very simple POC, which can be found [here](https://github.com/byrialsen/UwpGesturesManipulations)

The POC is quite simple and looks like this

```
<Page
    x:Class="GesturesManipulations.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:GesturesManipulations"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Canvas x:Name="container" Background="Silver">
        <Image
            x:Name="image"
            Stretch="Uniform"
            Canvas.Left="100" Canvas.Top="200"
            Source="Assets/windows10-uwp.jpg"
            ManipulationMode="TranslateX,TranslateY,Scale,Rotate"
            ManipulationDelta="OnManipulationDelta">

            <Image.RenderTransform>
                <TransformGroup>
                    <ScaleTransform x:Name="scaleTransform" />
                    <RotateTransform x:Name="rotateTransform" />
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="translateTransform" />
                </TransformGroup>
            </Image.RenderTransform>
        </Image>
    </Canvas>
</Page>
```

[codebehind]

```
private void OnManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    FrameworkElement origin = sender as FrameworkElement;
    FrameworkElement parent = origin.Parent as FrameworkElement;

    var localCoords = e.Position;
    var relativeTransform = origin.TransformToVisual(parent);
    Point parentContainerCoords = relativeTransform.TransformPoint(localCoords);
    var center = parentContainerCoords;

    // translate/panning
    translateTransform.X += e.Delta.Translation.X;
    translateTransform.Y += e.Delta.Translation.Y;

    rotateTransform.CenterX = center.X;
    rotateTransform.CenterY = center.Y;
    rotateTransform.Angle += e.Delta.Rotation;

    scaleTransform.CenterX = center.X;
    scaleTransform.CenterY = center.Y;
    scaleTransform.ScaleX *= e.Delta.Scale;
    scaleTransform.ScaleY *= e.Delta.Scale;
}
```

Overall the functionality seems to works. But it also seems like the transform center has some problems. Starting a new gestures really often the image makes a jumps/offset and manipulations sometimes use the wrong center.

I have tried a lot of stuff over the last few days but I can't seem to get hold of the real problem. Maybe I am just doing this to simple. Do I have to do stuff in some of the other manipulation events. Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check the MS official practice [BasicInput-Scenario 4](https://github.com/Microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/773db9338b5de0b1058097f77ad3ac68dbc0a73d/Samples/BasicInput/cs/4-XAMLManipulations.xaml.cs). This sample seems will not occur the behavior `jumps/offset and manipulations sometimes use the wrong center`.

Comment: The problem with that sample is that it only handles panning and rotation together. I believe it is the scaling and rotation together or maybe just the scaling that introduces the misbehavior in my sample.

Comment: FYI...I found another question on stackoverflow that has a working code example of what I am trying to do. If others are interested it can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36727020/uwp-manipulation-with-rotation-scale-and-pan)

Answer (score 0):

After struggling a lot with that center rotation problem, I finally found the solution.

According to a Microsoft [Blog entry](https://blogs.windows.com/windowsdeveloper/2017/05/25/uwp-evolution-touch-development/) the way to implement this is the following:

```
void ManipulateMe_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    previousTransform.Matrix = transforms.Value;

    // Get center point for rotation
    Point center = previousTransform.TransformPoint(new Point(e.Position.X, e.Position.Y));
    deltaTransform.CenterX = center.X;
    deltaTransform.CenterY = center.Y;

    // Look at the Delta property of the ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs to retrieve
    // the rotation, scale, X, and Y changes
    deltaTransform.Rotation = e.Delta.Rotation;
    deltaTransform.TranslateX = e.Delta.Translation.X;
    deltaTransform.TranslateY = e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```

But the problem is, that the e.Position value is NOT relative to the element where the ManipulationDelta event is called, but the element which was touched! So if you have multiple elements inside your element, for example a grid, then the e.Position is relative to the child element which was touched.
So we first need to transform the e.Position to the container element and then transform that to the screen position.

So the correct code should be:

```
void ManipulateMe_ManipulationDelta(object sender, ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs e)
{
    previousTransform.Matrix = transforms.Value;

    // Get center point for rotation

    var posX = e.Position.X;
    var posY = e.Position.Y;


    ////// FIRST GET TOUCH POSITION RELATIVE TO THIS ELEMENT ///
    if(e.Container != null)
    {
        var p = e.Container.TransformToVisual(this).TransformPoint(new Point(posX, posY)); //transform touch point position relative to this element
        posX = p.X;
        posY = p.Y;
    }        

    Point center = previousTransform.TransformPoint(new Point(posX, posY));
    deltaTransform.CenterX = center.X;
    deltaTransform.CenterY = center.Y;

    // Look at the Delta property of the ManipulationDeltaRoutedEventArgs to retrieve
    // the rotation, scale, X, and Y changes
    deltaTransform.Rotation = e.Delta.Rotation;
    deltaTransform.TranslateX = e.Delta.Translation.X;
    deltaTransform.TranslateY = e.Delta.Translation.Y;
}
```